# what does these pandas group by statement does?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am following a tutorial on how to build a recommender system and came upon this line

```
users_interactions_count_df = interactions_df.groupby(['personId', 'contentId']).size().groupby('personId').size()
```

The first groupby I believe groups the data first according to personID ,then contentID then shows its size but dont really understand what the next groupby will do ?

Source : [Building recommendation system in python](https://www.kaggle.com/gspmoreira/recommender-systems-in-python-101)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this sample data:

```
interactions_df = pd.DataFrame({
         'personId':list('XXYYWZWZ'),
         'contentId':list('aaaabbaa')
})

print (interactions_df)
  personId contentId
0        X         a
1        X         a
2        Y         a
3        Y         a
4        W         b
5        Z         b
6        W         a
7        Z         a
```

First get count per columns `personId` and `contentId`:

```
print (interactions_df.groupby(['personId', 'contentId']).size())
personId  contentId
W         a            1
          b            1
X         a            2
Y         a            2
Z         a            1
          b            1
dtype: int64
```

And then count by first level of `MultiIndex` created by `personId` column:

```
print (interactions_df.groupby(['personId', 'contentId']).size().groupby('personId').size())
personId
W    2
X    1
Y    1
Z    2
dtype: int64
```