# Got an error while trying to "groupby" this protion through pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, recommendation-engine

I want to build a recommendation system and follow a tutorial. I'm trying to groupby these columns but I got a bunch of weird errors and I can't understand why.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
import random
import sklearn

interactions_df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Rao/Desktop/Recommender System/users_interactions.csv')
interactions_df.head(3)

print(interactions_df.groupby(['personId', 'contentId']).size().groupby('personId').size())
```

I want this output:

```
print (interactions_df.groupby(['personId', 'contentId']).size())
personId  contentId
W         a            1
          b            1
X         a            2
Y         a            2
Z         a            1
          b            1
dtype: int64
```

But I got:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
last)
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\multi.py in 
get_value(self, series, key)
    617             try:
--> 618                 return _index.get_value_at(s, k)
    619             except IndexError:

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.get_value_at (pandas\index.c:2549)()

pandas\src\util.pxd in util.get_value_at (pandas\index.c:15951)()

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-25-22789f9d1e69> in <module>()
----> 1 print(interactions_df.groupby(['personId', 
'contentId']).size().groupby('personId').size())
      2 #print (interactions_df.groupby(['personId', 'contentId']).size())
      3 #print (interactions_df.groupby(['personId', 
'contentId']).size().groupby('personId').size())

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in 
groupby(self, by, axis, level, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze, 
**kwargs)
   3776         return groupby(self, by=by, axis=axis, level=level, 
as_index=as_index,
3777                        sort=sort, group_keys=group_keys, 
squeeze=squeeze,
-> 3778                        **kwargs)
   3779 
   3780     def asfreq(self, freq, method=None, how=None, 
normalize=False):


pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value 
(pandas\index.c:3332)()

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value 
(pandas\index.c:3035)()

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4018) 
()

pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item 
(pandas\hashtable.c:12368)()

pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item 
(pandas\hashtable.c:12322)()

KeyError: 'personId'
```

Comment: Why are you calling `groupby` twice?

Comment: If you get an error on a complex statement (here two groupby) make every call in sequence. It will be easier to find the cause for the error. Anyway the error suggest that there is no `personId` column in the dataframe...

Comment: @SergeBallesta but my dataset has column named 'personId'. Anyway, I tried to write separate statements but same error occurred

Comment: @JoshFriedlander I follow this tutorial: https://www.kaggle.com/gspmoreira/recommender-systems-in-python-101?scriptVersionId=1675789  and Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52850214/what-does-these-pandas-group-by-statement-does is a lil information about this line of code but I found errors while running this.

Comment: Print the head of the dataframe and show what you obtain. It could give a hint...

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your error with random data. See [pyfiddle](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/938c6e2d-bd7a-460f-91e9-3d7649b9db50/?i=true) (click Run).